# How to fetch the Key names of a deeply nested node in Firebase in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I want to get the key names of a nested node in firebase.

Here's the structure

```
"THIRD YEAR" : {
"DAA" : {
  "Mod1" : {
    "Calender" : "A downloadable link",
    "Clock" : "A downloadable link"
  }
},
"IOT" : {
  "Mod1" : {
    "Topic1" : "A downloadable link",
    "Topic2" : "A downloadable link"
  }
}
```

}

**Now, what is my aim?**

My aim is to get the name of the subjects 'DAA' and 'IOT' then I'm looking for the child 'Mod1' then I could easily access the values through a model class.

**What I have done?**

Well all I could do is only access the target values by hardcoding their paths like this

```
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("THIRD YEAR").child("DAA").child("Mod1")
```

and then doing the typical adding listeners stuff to get the required value.
But the aim here is not to hardcode the values as the app shall be dynamic.

Currently i'm here and what I am expecting from the log statement below are the values DAA and then IOT.

```
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("THIRD YEAR").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.i("Sub name", snapshot.getValue(TestModal.class).getTopicName());

            }
```

How do I do it ? Thank you for your time.
This is how this thing looks in firebase

[image]

Comment: what is the issue you are facing in your implementation?

Comment: It's not quite clear what is static and what is changing. If each item in the list has the same inner class, ten its just a state of parsing a list of json. (which comes down as an object)

Comment: I cannot fetch the name of the keys which I can assure will change as the database would get bigger. By keys I mean ( DAA  and Mod1 , IOT and Mod1)  @dinkar_kumar I am not able to programatically get the name of these keys, how do I do it ?

Comment: What I am willing to learn from you is how do I get the keys of a deeply nested branch in firebase provided the root of the branch (as I have shown in the code above ) @Blundell. If the keys were in the fashion of an arraylist i.e like 0,1,2..... n then it would have been easy, but the problem arises when the keys are meaningfull strings like in the above example are ( DAA  ,Mod1 ).

Comment: Overall what I am looking for is the code to get the keys of the above tree with the known key being THIRD YEAR which would be the reference of the rest of the tree inside of it. Then I would be able to fetch data and keys from complex and even more nested branches by generalising the concept. Hope that makes my doubt clear. :)

Comment: You could add another node :-) "Keys": "DAA, Mod1, IOT"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You only need to get the keys, "DAA" and "IOT"?